Can some please explain Isaiah 66:8 what is the revelation there? What is connected to?
What is the meaning of Isaiah 66:8 who Zion and who is the baby she brought forth. What’s the revelation behind the scripture?

Isa 66:8 - “Who has heard such a thing? Who has seen such things? Can
a land be born in one day? Can a nation be given birth all at once? As
soon as Zion was in labor, she also delivered her sons.


Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! Please consider how we see your question, whether your entire thoughts about this question are appearing to us in a way to understand what your question is, explicitly based upon this scripture. For example, it would be easier for the reader(s) to see the verse in question. You could make a quote of it here to read. Then, getting into the verse by using the words related to your question, explicitly explain what you do not understand to make the process one of unified research. In this way,  we will all discover the answer(s) together.

I believe this chapter is in reference to the future "travail" that Israel (the woman) must "endure unto the end" before Christ returns to earth to establish Israel's promised kingdom of priests to the world.  God is promising Israel that her 'birth pangs' will not be for naught (verse 9). I see the "sons" of "Zion" being a reference to the twelve tribes of Israel, with verse 7 foreshadowing Christ's first coming, and His second coming in verse 9.
Notice in Luke the scripture of Isaiah that Christ reads in the synagogue (just 5 chapters prior to the verses in question), and what He deliberately omits in His recitation:
Luke 4:16-21

And he came to Nazareth, where he had been brought up: and, as his custom was, he went into the synagogue on the sabbath day, and stood up for to read.
17 And there was delivered unto him the book of the prophet Esaias. And when he had opened the book, he found the place where it was written,
18 The Spirit of the Lord is upon me, because he hath anointed me to preach the gospel to the poor; he hath sent me to heal the brokenhearted, to preach deliverance to the captives, and recovering of sight to the blind, to set at liberty them that are bruised,
19 To preach the acceptable year of the Lord.
20 And he closed the book, and he gave it again to the minister, and sat down. And the eyes of all them that were in the synagogue were fastened on him.
21 And he began to say unto them, This day is this scripture fulfilled in your ears.

Here are the verses of Isaiah that He recited from (in my italics), and what He omitted (in my bold).  I included verse 3 for context:
Isaiah 61:1-3

The Spirit of the Lord God is upon me; because the Lord hath anointed me to preach good tidings unto the meek; he hath sent me to bind up the brokenhearted, to proclaim liberty to the captives, and the opening of the prison to them that are bound;
2 To proclaim the acceptable year of the Lord, and the day of vengeance of our God; to comfort all that mourn;
3 To appoint unto them that mourn in Zion, to give unto them beauty for ashes, the oil of joy for mourning, the garment of praise for the spirit of heaviness; that they might be called trees of righteousness, the planting of the Lord, that he might be glorified.

Christ came, thus "the acceptable year of the Lord".  However, "the day of vengeance" (Daniel's 70th week) has yet to come, which will be Israel's tribulation (Matthew 24:3-13), and why Christ did not read the second half of verse 2.  That day was not then or yet "fulfilled".

Thanks very much

IMO a couple of problems.  not sure how Luke would know that, Jesus read a particular page when the alleged eyewitnesses don’t even mention this in the gospel.  This Israel promised land and chosen people forever is a fallacy - there is no things as 'forever' (everlasting, never ending, eternal) apart from God, everything else has an ending.
Matt 21:43 - Therefore say I unto you, The kingdom of God shall be taken from you, and given to a nation bringing forth the fruits thereof.
